# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract count

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

On Zend_Db_Table_Abstract I'm using this code to get the count of results for my select:

```
$this->setTableName('visitors');
$select = $this->select()
               ->from('visitors')
               ->columns(array('total' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')))
               ->where('...');
$visits = $this->_fetch($select);
```

Is there a better way, ie, just to return the count. This returns some other data in an array... I just want the count of results. In straight mySQl the equivalent would be `select count(`mycol`) from visitors where ....`

Comment: only count. `$count = (int)$this->getAdapter()->fetchOne($select);`
try :)

Comment: `fetchOne()` Fetches the first column of the first row of the SQL result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is untested, but should get you started:

```
$results = $this->getAdapter()
  ->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM visitors WHERE ...")
  ->fetchAll();
$visits = $results[0]["total"];
```

You aren't required to use the Table/Select interface for every query.

---

update: +1 to the comment from @SMka, for pointing out that this can be even simpler:

```
$visits = $this->getAdapter()
  ->fetchOne("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM visitors WHERE ...");
```

Comment: Your last sentence is a relief!

Comment: I worked on Zend_Db_Select, and I tried to make it clear in the docs that the interface is to help when you need to build up a query piece by piece from application logic or variables.  It's not necessary to use that interface when you you can simply spell out the full SQL query in a string.  *SQL is already a domain-specific language.*

Comment: @Bill Karwin but parsing SQL takes time wouldn't  Zend_Db_Select with PDO extension gona save recourse ??

Comment: @jason bourne: Zend_Db_Select simply helps to put together a SQL query string.  The query string is still sent to the RDBMS server, where it is parsed just like if you wrote it yourself.  There is no savings.

Answer (score 4):

```
$count = $this->select()->from($this,'COUNT(*)')->query()->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: This looks interesting, do I add something like count( mycol) in the query() bit?

Comment: no nothing needed , you can replace $this with 'visitors' if you like too.

Comment: OK, but how do I add a WHERE condition, is it query('WHERE ...')?

Answer (score 1):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html

see `fetchOne`

```
$this->setTableName('visitors');
$select = $this->select()
               ->from('visitors')
               ->columns(array('total' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')))
               ->where('...');
$count = $this->getAdapter()->fetchOne($select);
```

Comment: Does that fetch all the data and then give the count, or just fetch the count?

Answer (score 0):

here ya go

```
public function fetchCount($data)
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table WHERE field = ".$data;

    $count = $this->db->fetchOne($sql, array('count'));

    return $count;
}
```